# Python: How to build a function that takes multiple objects of the same class as input parameter?

Tags: python, oop, linked-list

I am working with linked list in python.

Here are the two classes I have written to build a linked list:

```
class node:
    
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class linkedList:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

# Two linked lists are being created:
l1 = linkedList() #1st linked list
l1.head = node(1)
new_node1 = node(2)
l1.head.next = new_node1

l2 = linkedList() #2nd linked list
l2.head = node(10)
new_node2 = node(20)
l2.head.next = new_node2
```

Now, I would like to build a function inside the linkedList class which would take two linked lists and do various tasks on them like: comparison, concatenating linked lists etc.

But main challenge is I am not quite sure how to build a function that takes multiple objects of the same class as input parameter?

Your help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `def compare(l1: linkedList, l2:linkedList) -> int: ...`

Comment: What is the problem? To write a function which takes more than one parameter (technically you wrote it already in the code) or to check the class of an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class linkedList:
    
    #create function of linkedList class which takes exactly 2 linkedList objects:

    def function(obj1: linkedList, obj2: linkedList):
        pass #do whatever you need to do with those objects
```

then you can apply this function:

```
linkedList.function(LL1, LL2)
```

or alternatively you can do this:

```
class linkedList:
    
    def function(self, obj: linkedList):
        pass
```

this will apply function to object from which it was called and another object passed as an argument:

```
LL1.function(LL2)
```